# Why LSTM uses sigmoid function to mimic the gate mechanism instead of binary value(0/1)?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, sigmoid

In LSTM, we usually use sigmoid function to mimic the gates mechanism (soft), but the problem is in a lot of cases, such function gives a value around 0.5, which does not mean anything in terms of gates. Why don't use binary value (0/1) in LSTM, what is the basic idea and intuition using sigmoid function in LSTM and GRU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary function in your network would cause problems with backpropagation, since its not a 'nicely differentiable' function (the delta function, which is its derivative, won't play nice in numeric computations)

Answer (score 0):

A sigmoid gate outputs a value between 0 and 1. It describes how much information should be passed. The value of 0 indicates that "Nothing should get through", and a value of 1 means "Let everything get through". For further informations, I advise you to take a look on [colah's blog](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/).